# Pandas: how to add column with True/False if another column contain duplicate or not

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
d_test = {'name' : ['Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Dog', 'Ant', 'Beach']}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

I want to add column `duplicate` with True/Fasle for each entry. I want `False` only for case if there only one entry in the column `name` and `True` in any other cases. Here is expected output:

```
    name   duplicate
0   Beach  True
1   Dog    True
2   Bird   False
3   Dog    True
4   Ant    False
5   Beach  True
```

I am looking to `df.groupby('...')` method but I am not sure how to apply it to my case.

Comment: Wrong linked dupes, reopened.

Comment: @jezrael how exactly were they wrong?

Comment: @matszwecja  it is different with invert mask by `~`

Comment: Seriously, we now have two answers proposing the same approaches as in the previous duplicate and by the same authors to boot. The point of duplicates is to capture the *task*, not the incidental details of each situation. If the difference is just inverting or not, these are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
df_test['duplicate'] = df_test['name'].duplicated(keep=False)
print (df_test)
    name  duplicate
0  Beach       True
1    Dog       True
2   Bird      False
3    Dog       True
4    Ant      False
5  Beach       True
```

If need test number of counts, True if not match use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and compare for not equal:

```
N = 1
df_test['duplicate'] = df_test.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size').ne(N)
```